# Server Error in '/' Application. A ControlID must be specified in ControlParameter 'Product_Name'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, insert

I am new here and a beginner with APS and VB, I do have SQL experience. the problem I am having is I am trying to select two values in a VB aspx page.
one is a text box which can be types into, the other is a value which is selected from a drop downlist that looks as a table in my SQL database.
I want both values once entered and selected to be entered as a new row into another table of the same database, but I am getting the following error. and its driving me round in circles.
**A ControlID must be specified in ControlParameter 'Product_Name'.**

my code is as below, I suspect it is something simple that I am missing but I cannot see it for looking, can anyone help please?

```
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>



            <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DefaultMode="Insert">
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    Product_Name:
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Product_Name" DataValueField="Product_Name">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    Product_Description:
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Product_DescriptionTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Product_Description") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                    &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                </InsertItemTemplate>
            </asp:FormView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Incident_TrackerConnectionString %>" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Incidents] ( [I_Product_Name], [I_Product_Description]) VALUES ( @Product_Name, @Product_Description)">
                <InsertParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter Name="Product_Name" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Product_Description" Type="String" />
                </InsertParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Incident_TrackerConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="select Product_Name from dbo.products"></asp:SqlDataSource>

        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style2"></td>
        <td class="auto-style2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="auto-style1"></td>
        <td class="auto-style1"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<br />
<br />
```

Thanks Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nee to specify the `ControlID` & `PropertyName` like this:-

```
<InsertParameters>
     <asp:ControlParameter Name="Product_Name" ControlID="DropDownList1"
            PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
</InsertParameters>
```

**Edit:-**
Okay, since you are using `FormView`, you need to specify it like this:-

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
      DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Product_Name"
      DataValueField="Product_Name" SelectedValue=<%# Bind('Product_Name') %>>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

Then , bind the `InsertParameters` as:-

```
<InsertParameters>
     <asp:Parameter Name="Product_Name" Type="String" />
     <asp:Parameter Name="Product_Description" Type="String" />
</InsertParameters>
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the response, I have added the code as you suggest but I am now receiving the below error. ***Could not find control 'DropDownList1' in ControlParameter 'Product_Name'.*** am I missing something else from my code somewhere? thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi thanks that sorted it, great job, now I have the initial issue sorted though it does give me another problem. I need to them have another DDL that is dependent on the choice of the first DDL is this possible? thanks Kevin

Comment: Just a quick follow up question is there a way to do what I am attempting and above another way not using the insert template I have used?

Comment: Yeah you can always create a form and insert details using custom ADO.NET code.